# Tools to visualize an HTML document tree (DOM tree)

Tags: graph-visualization, dom, tree-structure

I want to visualize the document structure of a HTML website.

What I would like to have is something like this:

[image]

Are there any known tools that do this and where the results can be saved as a bitmap file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use LaTeX to create the DOM representation.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

  \Tree[.table 
         [.thead 
           [.tr 
             [.th [.\textit{Vorname} ] ]
             [.th [.\textit{Nachname} ] ]
           ]
         ]              
         [.tbody 
           [.tr 
             [.td [.\textit{Donald} ] ]
             [.td [.\textit{Duck} ] ]
           ]
         ]
       ]

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've just tried using two libraries.

First I converted the dom to JSON using [Jsonml](http://www.jsonml.org/)

```
var jsonData = JsonML.fromHTMLText(htmlData);
```

Then used [Json Editor](https://github.com/DavidDurman/FlexiJsonEditor) or [Json Viewer](http://jquery-jsonviewer-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html) for visualizing it

View Samples in jsFiddle

1. [Using Json Editor](http://jsfiddle.net/UUL5k/19/)
2. [Using Json Viewer](http://jsfiddle.net/UUL5k/18/)

Hope this may help you.

Comment: the github raw url don't work. You should change it. See more here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/815507