# Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub

Tags: javascript, github

When I try to change the linked reference of a local JavaScript file to a GitHub raw version my test file stops working. The error is:

> Refused to execute script from ... because its MIME type (`text/plain`) is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Is there a way to disable this behavior or is there a service that allows linking to GitHub raw files?

Working code:

```
<script src="bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script>
```

Non-working code:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/master/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script>
```

Comment: rawgit.com is the new domain now

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779197/linking-files-directly-from-github/24425890#24425890

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - only if your source files *never change*. `rawgit` cache [never updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23537239/104380).

Comment: very good point.

Comment: @vsync you can append the date to the url as a query param and it will update (won't use the cache, force new read)

Comment: 2019: JUST SKIP ALL ANSWERS MENTIONING RAW OR RAWGIT. Rawgit is dead. Go down to the answer from chharwey and upvote it until it gets to the top. That is the good one: the simplest, that uses the official GitHub preferred approach.

Comment: Use https://www.jsdelivr.com/?docs=gh, it works

Comment: @MarcoFaustinelli So much right!

Comment: Related (but older) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901066/raw-github-js-file-not-loading-direct-link-like-cdn

Answer (score 1082, accepted):

There *is* a good workaround for this, now, by using [jsdelivr.net](//www.jsdelivr.com).

**Steps**:

1. Find your link on GitHub, and click to the "Raw" version.
2. Copy the URL.
3. Change `raw.githubusercontent.com` to `cdn.jsdelivr.net`
4. Insert `/gh/` before your username.
5. Remove the `branch` name.
6. (Optional) Insert the *version* you want to link to, as `@version` (if you do not do this, you will get the *latest* - which may cause long-term caching)

---

**Examples**:

```
http://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo>/<branch>/path/to/file.js
```

Use this URL to get the latest version:

```
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/<username>/<repo>/path/to/file.js
```

Use this URL to get a specific version or commit hash:

```
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/<username>/<repo>@<version or hash>/path/to/file.js
```

**For production environments**, consider targeting a specific tag or commit-hash rather than the branch. Using the *latest* link may result in long-term caching of the file, causing your link to not be updated as you push new versions. Linking to a file by commit-hash or tag makes the link unique to version.

---

**Why is this needed?**

In 2013, GitHub started using `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`, which instructs more modern browsers to enforce strict MIME type checking. It then returns the raw files in a MIME type returned by the server, preventing the browser from using the file as-intended (if the browser honors the setting).

For background on this topic, please refer to [this discussion thread](//bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180007).

Comment: Also works for gists. I was able to replace `gist.githubusercontent.com` with `rawgist.com` and got it working.

Comment: I don't know who mantains this site rawgit, but don't use it in production. You would have an unknown third party that can inject any javascript in your site.

Comment: Keep in mind that its caching files permanently. So when you update your file it will keep the old version.

Comment: @Maciej Krawczyk - yes - the page explicitly encourages you to use a commit-specific link, rather than a branch link, for exactly this reason.

Comment: This is far from ideal, since the *rawgit* [never updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23537239/104380) the file if it was updated on github, therefor one must update all the urls using the rawgit everywhere... sucks.

Comment: @vsync Though I think I already covered that limitation in the answer, I edited just now to make it even more clear/explicit both what the problem is - and how to overcome it for folks wanting to use the CDN features.

Comment: Here's a script that change the URL to the correct (latest) jsdelivr version for you:
`var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
path = [...path.slice(1, 3), ...path.slice(4, path.length)];
path = path.join('/');
window.location = 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/' + path;
`

Comment: Come on, people, seriously?! Approach with `jsdelivr` or `rawgit` introduces a huge vulnerability. You basically trust some random guys your fronted app. @chharvey answer is way much better.

Answer (score 61):

This is no longer possible. GitHub has explicitly disabled JavaScript
hotlinking, and newer versions of browsers respect that setting.

[Heads up: nosniff header support coming to Chrome and Firefox](//github.com/blog/1482)

Answer (score 26):

`rawgithub.com` redirects to `rawgit.com` So the above example would now be

`http://rawgit.com/user/package/master/link.min.js`

Comment: Visit https://rawgit.com/ and paste the url for the file or gist. It will generate a valid url for you.

Comment: **rawgit** is now discontinued (as of 2018-10-08): https://rawgit.com/ . recommend updating this answer.

Comment: RawGit is now in a sunset phase and will soon shut down. Read more https://rawgit.com/

Answer (score 20):

**GitHub Pages** is GitHub’s official solution to this problem.

`raw.githubusercontent` makes all files use the `text/plain` MIME type, even if the file is a CSS or JavaScript file. So going to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/‹user›/‹repo›/‹branch›/‹filepath›` will not be the correct MIME type but instead a plaintext file, and linking it via `<link href="..."/>` or `<script src="..."></script>` won’t work—the CSS won’t apply / the JS won’t run.

[GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) hosts your repo at a special URL, so all you have to do is check-in your files and push. Note that in most cases, GitHub Pages requires you to commit to a special branch, `gh-pages`.

On your new site, which is usually `https://‹user›.github.io/‹repo›`, every file committed to the `gh-pages` branch (the most recent commit) is present at this url. So then you can link to your js file via `<script src="https://‹user›.github.io/‹repo›/file.js"></script>`, and this will be the correct MIME type.

### Do you have build files?

Personally, my recommendation is to run this branch parallel to `master`. On the `gh-pages` branch, you can edit your `.gitignore` file to *check in* all the dist/build files you need for your site (e.g. if you have any minified/compiled files), while *keeping them ignored* on your `master` branch. This is useful because you typically don’t want to track changes in build files in your regular repo. Every time you want to update your hosted files, simply merge `master` into `gh-pages`, rebuild, commit, and then push.

*(protip: you can merge and rebuild in the same commit with these steps:)*

```
$ git checkout gh-pages
$ git merge --no-ff --no-commit master  # prepare the merge but don’t commit it (as if there were a merge conflict)
$ npm run build                         # (or whatever your build process is)
$ git add .                             # stage the newly built files
$ git merge --continue                  # commit the merge
$ git push origin gh-pages
```

Answer (score 9):

https://raw.githack.com/

found this site supply a CDN for

- remove `nosniff` http header
- fix `mime type` by ext name

and this site:

https://rawgit.com/

> NOTE: RawGit has reached the end of its useful life

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a browser extension to remove the `X-Content-Type-Options` response header for `raw.githubusercontent.com` files. There are a couple of browser extensions to modify response headers.

1. [Requestly: Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) & [Firefox](https://requestly.io/downloads/firefox/)
2. [Modify Header Value: Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-header-value/)

#### Remove X-Content-Type-Options response header using Requestly

- [Install Requestly](https://requestly.io/downloads) for your browser
- Open [Rules Page](https://app.requestly.io/rules)
- Click create rule & Select Modify Headers
  In Source field, enter `Url` -> `Contains` -> `raw.githubusercontent.com`
- In Response Headers section, `Remove` -> `X-Content-Type-Options`

[image: Requestly Modify Headers Screenshot]

### How to test

I created a simple JS Fiddle to test out if we can use raw github files as scripts in our code. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8q6h25g/2/) with the following code

```
<center id="msg"></center>

<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sachinjain024/practicebook/master/web-extensions-master/storage/background.js"></script>
<script>
try {
  if (typeof BG.Methods !== 'undefoned') {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Script evaluated successfully!';
  }
} catch (e) {
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Problem evaluating script';
}
</script>
```

If you see `Script evaluated successfully!`, It means you are able to use raw github file in your code
Otherwise `Problem evaluating script` indicates that there is some problem while executing the script from raw github source.

**Note** This will only work on your machine So you won't be able to deploy to production. This approach lets you quickly use the files in any Github repostiory without much hassle.

Disclaimer: I am the author of [Requestly](https://requestly.io) So you can blame for anything you don't like.

Comment: rawgit.com is no longer a thing so your post needs updating @Paul

Comment: Thanks, @Hello! Updated my answer and removed the solution referring to rawgit.com

Answer (score 6):

My use case was to load '[bookmarklets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)' direclty from my Bitbucket account which has same restrictions as Github. The work around I came up with was to AJAX  for the script and run `eval` on the response string, below snippet is based on that approach.

```
<script>
    var sScriptURL ='<script-URL-here>'; 
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    oReq.addEventListener("load", 
       function fLoad() {eval(this.responseText + '\r\n//# sourceURL=' + sScriptURL)}); 
    oReq.open("GET", sScriptURL); oReq.send(); false;
</script>
```

Note that appending of `sourceURL` comment is to allow for debuging of the script within browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 5):

To make things clear and short

`//raw.githubusercontent.com` --> `//rawgit.com`

Note that this is handled by rawgit's development hosting and not their cdn for production hosting

Comment: Default raw URL seems to have changed since this answer so conversion is now `https://raw.githubusercontent.com` --> `https://rawgit.com` Otherwise this answer is clearest and works.

Comment: **rawgit** is now discontinued (as of 2018-10-08): https://rawgit.com/ . recommend updating this answer.

Answer (score 1):

When a file is uploaded to github you can use it as external source or free hosting. Troy Alford has explained it well above. But to make it easier let me tell you some easy steps then you can use a github raw file in your site:

Here is your file's link:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/master/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js

Now to execute it you have to remove **https://** and the dot( . ) between **raw** and **githubusercontent**

Like this:

**rawgithubusercontent.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/master/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js**

Now when you will visit this link you will get a link that can be used to call your javascript:

Here is the final link:

https://rawgit.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/master/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js

Similarly if you host a css file you have to do it as mentioned above. It is the easiest way to get simple link to call your external css or javascript file hosted on github.

I hope this is helpful.

Referance URL: http://101helper.blogspot.com/2015/11/store-blogger-codes-on-github-boost-blogger-speed.html

Comment: **rawgit** is now discontinued (as of 2018-10-08): https://rawgit.com/ . recommend updating this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error was shown due to the comments at the beginning of file , You can solve this issue  , by simply creating your own file without comment and push to git, it shows no error

For proof you can try these two file with same code of easy pagination :

[without comment](https://cdn.rawgit.com/dsuntos/cdn/866bb30f/pagination.js)

[with comment](https://cdn.rawgit.com/st3ph/jquery.easyPaginate/083746fb/lib/jquery.easyPaginate.js)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you, what I did is change to

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script>
```

It works for me.

Comment: change from what to what? please show the before and after

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

---

**original**

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antelove19/qrcodejs/master/qrcode.min.js
```

**cdn.jsdelivr.net**

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/antelove19/qrcodejs/qrcode.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way:
`<script type="text/plain" src="http://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/file.js"></script>`
Served by GitHub, 
and

## very

reliable.
With `text/plain`
[image]
 Without `text/plain`
[image]

Comment: This is the best solution, it just works and makes so much sense.

Comment: no. all this does is prevent the script from even running

Comment: It wont work anymore soon. From my Android device logcat: "Fetching scripts with an invalid type/language attributes is deprecated and will be removed in M56, around January 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5760718284521472 for more details."

Answer (score 0):

`raw.github.com` is not truely raw access to file asset,
but a view rendered by Rails.
So accessing `raw.github.com` is much heavier than needed.
I don't know why `raw.github.com` is implemented as a Rails view.
Instead of fix this route issue, GitHub added a `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header.

Workaround:

- Put the script to `user.github.io/repo`
- Use a third party CDN like rawgit.com.

Comment: For anyone else confused by this, they did it intentionally. You used to be able to simply use `raw.github.com` to load files - and then github realized they were being used as a CDN, which was causing them far too much traffic. As a result, they changed it to this type of rendering with the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header, specifically to preclude people from using their service that way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if generating your markup server-side, you can just fetch and inject.
For example, in JSTL you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <c:import url="https://raw.github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/master/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js" />
</script>
```

They don't allow hotlinking for a reason, so probably bad form if you want to be a good citizen. I'd suggest you cache that javascript and only actually re-fetch periodically as you see fit.