# Using paperjs with jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle, paperjs

I just found out about [paperjs](http://paperjs.org/), an awesome framework for vector graphics that you probably already heard of.

I stumbled upon a problem though, I absolutely can NOT figure out how to make it work with jsfiddle! The few examples I found online were only working because all the code was jammed in the HTML section, in a paperscript tag.

Any idea how to make the "Javascript" section work, thus making use of the syntax coloring?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you post a link of the jsFiddle where you have tried to use PaperJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not put your paperjs code in the javascript panel by default.
You need to hack jsFiddler to do this.
See [the document from jsFiddler](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html)

> Please set the Code Wrap to no wrap(head) (default is onLoad) and Franework to No-library (pure JS).
>
> Similar to CoffeeScript, Paperscript requires the script tag to be the type of text/paperscript and provide the id of the canvas element in the canvas parameter. Enter following into the HTML panel and you’ll be able to write Paperscript in JavaScript panel.

```
<canvas id="some-unique-id" resize keepalive="true" style='height: 200; width: 200;'>    </canvas>
<script>(function(){var s="script",n='\n',d=document,b=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[2].innerHTML.split(n);d.write('<'+s+' type="text/paperscript" canvas="' + document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].id + '">'+b.slice(2,b.length-2).join(n)+'</'+s+'>')})()</script>
```

> Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/LrGEm/12/

Comment: I got this error: "Refused to execute script from ... because its MIME type (text/plain) is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." But I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/696973) that says raw.github should be changed to rawgithub and updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LrGEm/317/

Answer (score 2):

There is also sketch.paperjs.org

[Sketch.paperjs.org](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)

Comment: the best one for paper.js

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can just use https://www.jsbin.com to do your coding . It will allow JS to be written in the javascript place holder .

Comment: I have never heard of jsbin, it seems like a good alternative to jsfiddle!

Could you explain more clearly how to use paperscript in jsbin? Still can't seem to make it work and jsfiddle is really acting up.