# Firefly Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I put this in my head, 
there is no other jquery stuff in there.

Can anyone suggest why this is not working.
my page is here - [www.haelu.co.nf](http://www.haelu.co.nf)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/motyar/firefly/master/jquery-firefly-0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.firefly({
            images : ['http://www.itsfirefly.com/images/fly1by1.png','http://www.itsfirefly.com/images/fly2by2.png'],   //Fly images        
            total : 165, //number of flies
            on: '#header' //id of div
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: You're using a fairly old version of jQuery. You're getting an error from the firefly plugin that might be due to that.

Comment: I am using the exact version that was given on the download page. I'm just following instructions. Originally I was trying with the latest jquery but that didn't seem to work either

Comment: Ah - well your problem is that there is no "header" `<div>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Working Solution

Since there are issues with accessing the file from GitHub, alternatively you can get the [script](http://www.jongaulin.com/articles/firefly/jquery.firefly.js) from the developer's demo page, which is **not advisable**.

#### Errors

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://raw.github.com/motyar/firefly/master/jquery-firefly-0.2.js". www.haelu.co.nf/:9
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/motyar/firefly/master/jquery-firefly-0.2.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. www.haelu.co.nf/:1
```

#### Solution

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jongaulin.com/articles/firefly/jquery.firefly.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.firefly({
            images : ['http://www.itsfirefly.com/images/fly1by1.png','http://www.itsfirefly.com/images/fly2by2.png'],   //Fly images        
            total : 165, //number of flies
            on: '#header' //id of div
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### Fiddle: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/AWuNiDo/1)

Comment: That's a different version of the plugin you're using.  In particular, that "on" configuration parameter is ignored by that version.

Comment: ok cool. this firefly script works. The one I downloaded also doesn't work. And this also works with the latest jquery too

Comment: Can anyone suggest how I can get my logo to come in front of the flies, instead of them flying over everything? I tried checking the source for www.itsfirefly.com but I can't work it out how they did it

Answer (score 1):

You're telling the plugin to put the effect on an element with the id "header", but there is no such element on your page.

Comment: good point. although even with that part there, it seems to work with the change of firefly script.

Comment: @Haelu yes, because the older version of Firefly pays no attention to that configuration parameter. It does not support that feature - you can only apply the effect to the whole page.

Comment: the new version doesn't seem to work at all for me, even when I remove the element indicator. I'll just stick with the old one that works

Answer (score 0):

Opening this in chrome it won't execute the firefly script.

This is the error I see in the console.

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/motyar/firefly/master/jquery-firefly-0.2.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I think this should solve your problem.

[Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/how-to-link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-from-github)

http://rawgithub.com/

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox either, and Firefox doesn't refuse to run the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://raw.github.com/motyar/firefly/master/jquery-firefly-0.2.js". www.haelu.co.nf/:9
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/motyar/firefly/master/jquery-firefly-0.2.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. www.haelu.co.nf/:1
```