# How to run javascript in Android KitKat WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have following code in my WebView

```
<script src="remote src" param1="value1" param2="value2" ... />;
```

When it runs on Androids, lower than Kitkat, I use typical

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(..)
```

and script works fine. But, as we know, in KitKat WebView had absolutely changed, and scripts should be run as

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(script, callback);
```

and now is very unclear how to run my script, which is rendered with the rest of the page, in KitKat.

Comment: Have you remembered to call `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`?

Comment: Of cource, otherwise code will not be run under Android lower than KitKat

Comment: For your `loadDataWithBseURL()` scenario, is the string you are passing into it literally the `<script>` tag that you have shown?

Comment: No, it is typical html page, starts from <html><head>..<head><body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
String jScript = "(function() {\n" +
                    "var p=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];\n" +
                    "var s=document.createElement(\"script\");\n" +
                    "s.type=\"text/javascript\";\n" +
                    "s.src=\"http://pathtoscript/jscript.js\";\n" +
                    "s.async = true;\n" +
                    "p.appendChild(s);\n" +
                "}\n" +
            "})();\n";

webView.evaluateJavascript(jScript, callback);
```

But in this case i don't know is there possibility to get a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked into supporting loading of remote JS.

I have tried the following:

Loading a file through loadUrl("file://....") with an absolute path for a remote js file i.e.

Loading a html string into the webview with an absolute path for a remote js file

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("content://com.example.remotejs/", htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Loading a html string with a valid base url and a relative remote js file

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://labs.gauntface.co.uk/", htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Script tag:

All of the above worked. Can you please provide an example - my source is hosted here: https://github.com/gauntface/QuickWebViewExamples/tree/master/RemoteJSTest

Comment: Useless comment. My question is about how to execute scrit with remote src. I cannot cut it and put is as a parameter of a method evaluateJavascript()

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. So you are loading a html file or string into the WebView and loading javascript similar to: <script src="http://www.mysite.com/somejs.js" param1="value1" param2="value2" ... />; Where the 'http://www.mysite.com" was loaded as the base parameter of loadBaseUrl?

Answer (score 0):

The script should still execute fine in KK if it's inline inside the content that you pass to `loadDataWithBaseUrl`. The new `evaluateJavaScript` API is intended to execute script in the context of the document currently loaded in the WebView, *after* it has been loaded.

Prior to KK, developers would call `loadUrl` passing in a `javascript:` URL to achieve the same effect. The new API simplifies this, and allows a callback to be executed when the script has been run.

Hope this helps to clarify.

Comment: _The script should still execute fine_ But it doesn't execute!! Just in KitKat

Comment: Ok. Can you share the script? If not, try remote debugging in case there are any errors being thrown - see https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simplier.

Problem is now ith KitKat, but with Github

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/1346120