# jQuery scroll function not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a small problem I've tried to solve, but it seems like I can't wrap my head around it. I'm a new programmer so it would be nice if anyone here knew what I'm maybe doing wrong since I don't have much experience making this stuff....

I made something I call as skill bar on [my Portfolio website](http://kasperdesings.com/), go to portfolio and you can see it under "Web development skills" there is a skill bar, but it only works in explore and Firefox, but I can't seem to get it to work in Chrome, here is the code:

```
   $("#page02").waypoint(function () {
        $('#skill1').animate({ width: "50%" }, 1500);
        $('#skill2').animate({ width: "35%" }, 1500);
        $('#skill3').animate({ width: "40%" }, 1500);
        $('#skill4').animate({ width: "35%" }, 1500);
        $('#skill5').animate({ width: "25%" }, 1500);
        $('#skill6').animate({ width: "30%" }, 1500);
    });
```

I would greatly appreciate any kind of feedback I could get!

Comment: check errors under browser developer tools.. I guess the waypoint plug-in is not loaded..I see some error related to MIME type in my chrome browser..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github see for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change script reference in your html page from

```
https://raw.github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/master/waypoints.min.js
```

to

```
https://rawgithub.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/master/waypoints.min.js
```

it should work..