# how can I force cdn.rawgit.com use updated file

Tags: github, cdn

I am using cdn.rawgit.com to host some of my scripts and css for a project but I cannot refresh it. According to the FAQ:

> Requests to cdn.rawgit.com are routed through MaxCDN's super fast content delivery network, and are cached permanently the first time they're loaded. This results in the best performance and reduces load on RawGit and on GitHub, but it means that reloading won't fetch new changes from GitHub.

Does this mean I can never refresh? Or is there a way to force a refresh to use the most recent version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, permanent means never.

From the documentation:

> Since files are not refreshed after the first request, it's best to use a specific tag or commit URL, not a branch URL.

This wouldn't *update* the file per-se, but it would allow you to specify the new version.

Comment: Thanks @JohnD, So instead of using `script.js` I should append a version like `script.v1.js` ?

Comment: You would want to link to a specific commit or tag, eg. `https://cdn.rawgit.com/rgrove/rawgit/bb0f1b31787939122aab676759a225cb29573931/web.js`

Answer (score 3):

I just created a page with github pages and I hosted the files there. You create a repository, in settings create the page then when you update the files it will automatically do it for you!

Comment: This is pretty intuitive. Maybe expand your answer a little more!

Comment: You create a repository on Github and upload your files to it. Then, in settings, you enable github pages on the repository. As a result, you can go to [your username].github.io/[your repository name]/[your file name] @ThomasW

Answer (score 1):

Since rawgit.com is shutting down you want to use [combinatronics.com](https://combinatronics.com) it is an alternative for [rawgit.com](https://rawgit.com)

It also automatically gets the latest file.

Comment: The UI is not responsive when I copy-pasted the URL. But it seems like a good alternative

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to refresh a cdn link. But there is a way of doing this.
Instead of specifying the URL directly:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/file.txt
```

you can make it tag specific like this one

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/1.2/file.txt
```

So when you change the file, make a draft release and change the tag 1.2 to the tag release you made recently!