# CSS Sliding views with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-router

I am trying to achieve the same effect of sliding in/out views as found here:

http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1

Ive created a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ST49iozWWtYRYRdcGGQL?p=preview

But my entire ui-view completely disappears when i copy the CSS from the link above and think it could be down to the `position: relative` in my `container`

CSS:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
html body {
  font-size: 140%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 430px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.l-one-whole {
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

CSS needed to add:

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter,
.slide.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slide.ng-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}
.slide.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.slide.ng-leave-active {
    left: -100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>    

  <main class="l-one-whole">
    <section class="container">
      <article class="l-one-whole">

        <div ui-view class="slide"></div>

      </article>
    </section>
  </main>

</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('view1', {
      url: '/view1',
      templateUrl: 'page1.html'
    })
    .state('view2', {
      url: '/view2',
      templateUrl: 'page2.html'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/view1');
});
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

I think this is what you are looking for: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/e5BUJsq8Ipw7vuwyLZPO?p=preview)

I added the following styles to make animations work:

```
/* Transition effects */
.l-one-whole {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.slide.ng-enter,
.slide.ng-leave {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slide.ng-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide.ng-enter-active {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.slide.ng-leave {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.slide.ng-leave-active {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

I used transform instead of `left` because AFAIK it enables browser to accelerate animation using GPU increasing performance.

I hope I am not missing anything.

Answer (score 7):

Result: http://plnkr.co/edit/vhGSiA?p=preview

I have use Angular 1.3.15 instead of 1.2.9

Simplified HTML

```
  <section class="container">
    <div ui-view class="slide-left"></div>
  </section>
```

and more CSS

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.slide-left.ng-enter, .slide-left.ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}
.slide-left.ng-enter {
  z-index: 101;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.slide-left.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.slide-left.ng-leave {
  z-index: 100;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.slide-left.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
form {  /* contents within ui-view */
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/dlukez/ui-router/angular-1.2/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dlukez/ui-router/angular-1.2/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

[Updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IkPePLxgiQL7PBCthy8X?p=preview)

Detail explaination can be found here:

[Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)

Comment: thanks for this, but not sure how this solves my issue?

Comment: sorry, maybe i misunderstood you question? did you see the updated plnkr? i opened you plnkr,and there page1 completely disappear. Is that the problem you want to solve?

Comment: it think there may be some confusion, i am trying to get my views to slide in and out like the above above... but thanks for looking at the above.. see here with the CSS: http://plnkr.co/edit/uML2qvz1szlIwts0FmEu?p=preview

Comment: see example of sliding views: http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1

Comment: you should check his css definitions(app.css) via developer tools. actually add a slide class is not enough.