# Jquery script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason my code that i am running right now is not working. I have a menu on the left hand side and it should be when someone clicks it it will stay active on that menu. However it is not working.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/raw/master/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script>
(function () {
    $('ul.menu li').click(function () {
        $('ul.menu li').removeClass('active');
        return $(this).addClass('active');
    });
}.call(this));
</script>

</head>
<body>
......
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Dashboard</li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Messages</li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</li>
      <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-group"></i>Friends</li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Settings</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
.....
```

Would anyone know why this is? 
Thanks

Comment: `return $(this).addClass('active');` makes no sense. Why are you returning a jQuery object?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in your console? If so could you post them?

Comment: use `document.ready` ... an IIFE is not the same thing. Your code is running before elements exist

Comment: github is not a CDN, they are loading it as a document.. Not a javascript mime type. As suggested, you need to change where you load this file from.. Always test a script locally to the project and then when about to go live, use a CDN such as googles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.call(this)`, you can wrap it up inside `$(document)`'s `ready` function this way:

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.menu li').click(function () {
        $('ul.menu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

And remove the `return` statement. Also, I couldn't find jQuery added to the page. Kindly add jQuery like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After replacing your GitHub based URL, with [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/)'s URL, your final code should look like:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/style.css" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/master/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $('ul.menu li').click(function () {
        $('ul.menu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  ......
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Dashboard</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Messages</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</li>
    <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-group"></i>Friends</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Settings</li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
.....
```

Comment: I agree with this post, also the coffee script is hosted on github which does not work as a CDN.. The op will need to download it locally to their server.. Check the browser console when viewing the JS directly to see the mime type of document... Its trying to load the JS as a HTML file...

Comment: @Mayhem Check the update.

Comment: Perfect thank u very much! Ur a boss xx

Comment: @TroubleEagle You are welcome! `:)`

Comment: Glad its working now, didnt see any point in writing an answer after seeing this one was correct

Answer (score 1):

You try to append `click` event handler to your `li` elements when they are not in the DOM yet - your html markup comes later.

Move your script to just before closing `</body>` tag.
Also I would shorten it to just:

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function () {
    $('ul.menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

By the way - do you include jQuery lib anywhere on your page? If not, the script won't work too. Include jQuery lib somewhere in the `head` section on your page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also great :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the page is refusing to execute the script from the github url. I ran your code locally and was having issues getting the browser use the url you provided. You could use Google's CDN,

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or it looks like there is another stackoverflow post about getting github repos working, [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)

Goodluck