# Two-way Binders in Rivet.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, rivets.js, two-way

I have created a binder in rivets.js which binds to multiple attributes of an element from the given model.As I want a single binder for a my model object in JavaScript.

```
//Model 
var login = {
         test1 : {text:"myData1",color:"myColor1"},
         test2 : {text:"myData2",color:"myColor2"}
        }

//My Custom Binder
rivets.binders.customize= function(el, value) {
  el.style.color = value.color;
  el.text = value.text;
}

//html
<a rv-customize='login.test1'></a>
```

I have also binded the login model to UI page which I want the Dom updated as well.

```
//#myDOM => login
rivets.bind($('#myPage'), {login: login})
```

And now I use a form with couple of input tags to modify the model which is not in current context, I mean I bind **login.test1** to that form separately.

```
//#myForm => login.test1
rivets.bind($('#myForm'), {model: login.test1}) 

//#myForm 
<form>
//...
<input rv-value='model.color' type='text'/>
<input rv-value='model.text' type='text'/>
//...
</form>
```

When I alter the input in above form inputs, the model gets changed and is reflected in **login object** . But same is not reflected in DOM or UI.

And If I take the same scenario and just bind a single attribute like below  the flow works fine and any changes from input to model gets reflected in DOM.

```
rivets.binders.color = function(el, value) {
  el.style.color = value
}
```

Am I missing something ? Are such kind of binders with multiple bindings to attributes possible ? Is there any extra configuration I need to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing in the parent object of the two properties you are interested in, you would have to use a similar technique as with a computed property, described in the rivets.js [manual](http://rivetsjs.com/docs/guide/#computed-properties). Like this:

```
<a rv-customize='login.test1<test1.text test1.color'></a>
```

This tells rivets to update your binder when either text or color changes.

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tu3y1k9y/6/)

Comment: I just checked it (firefox), and still seems to be working perfectly. If I change input color to blue, the anchor tag changes to blue, and if I change the text input, it changes the text. What browser are you using, and are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Okay, found the issue. In firefox it was working fine, but in chrome it was giving `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../rivets.bundled.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` Solution (from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github/18049842#18049842) was to change to `https://cdn.rawgit.com/...`. Should be working now.