# Google markercluster not being created

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new to the Google clustered maps API and trying to use it in my website.

```
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script> 
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>


function createcluster(){
alert(markerlist.length);
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerlist, {
        gridSize:40,
        minimumClusterSize: 2
    });
    }
```

I have used the above imports in a script tag and created markerCluster as shown in above code.  I have checked markerlist, it is fine.  But markerCluster is not being created.  Can someone help me with this issue?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to the following post regarding the Google MarkerCluster library should provide a solution:

[MarkerCluster V3 stopped working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37184213/1301937)

Comment: Thanks for the help.I have been banging my head to solve this problem since 2 hrs.

Comment: Glad it helped and please can you mark it as useful (if you haven't already)