# Google maps stop showing points v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi  i have trouble to find what  case a problem to showing  the way point on goggle maps as  there  were no changes in the code  for  a wile. way point stop showing  about last week. im not familiar with  google api

```js
 

    
var map = null;
var markerArray = []; //create a global array to store markers
var myPoints = 
[ [52.664167, -8.509825,' HQ','favicon.ico'] ,[52.836346, -6.913117,'point 1','http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png ' ],[52.836202, -6.912101,'point2','http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png ' ]];
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.112, -7.448),
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var mcOptions = {
        gridSize: 30,
        maxZoom: 15
    };
    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
    });

    // Add markers to the map
    // Set up markers based on the number of elements within the myPoints array
    for(var i=0; i<myPoints.length; i++){
        createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(myPoints[i][0], myPoints[i][1]), myPoints[i][2], myPoints[i][3]);
  
    }
 
 
    
    mc.addMarkers(markerArray , true);
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

function createMarker(latlng, html, icons) {
    var contentString = html;
  var links = icons;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
  icon: links ,
      
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
    });
 
  
 

   // marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    
    markerArray.push(marker); //push local var marker into global array
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 750px;" ></div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using `MarkerClusterer` which is a part of google maps utility library, which was moved recently. Somebody probably referenced the library straight from code.google.com/svn/... in your project, where it's not available anymore and that's why it's broken. You need to find all libraries which are referenced from https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn and replace then with your own links.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179980/markercluster-v3-stopped-working-properly), user had very similar issues to yours.

Also! check this [question and answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171426/google-maps-api-v3-infobox-js-removed)!!, there are users who experienced issues with the same library, to get more information. Read all answers, as replacing https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn with https://rawgit.com/googlemaps/... is not a correct solution, you should download the library assets into your project and reference them from there or use CDN (but not git!).