# Cluster image on Google Map v3 is broken

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been using Google Map v3 since a long time. Few weeks ago, one of my client reported that they are not able to see the cluster image(the default one) on Google map.

[image: Previous Image of Cluster]

I found that the Cluster image is broken. Using Fiddler I got the [URL](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/m1.png) of the image and pasted it in browser. I got 404 Error.

Is anyone is aware about if anything is wrong on Google Map API? Does they have discontinued this feature?

Even on the Demo example of Google Map Cluster, the image is not coming up:
[URL](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/simple_example.html)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `MarkerClusterer` library is not part of Google Maps API, it's a third party library called `google maps utility library`. Anyway this library was moved recently. Somebody probably referenced the cluster image straight from code.google.com/svn/... in your project, where it's not available anymore and that's why it's broken.

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179980/markercluster-v3-stopped-working-properly), user had very similar issues to yours.

Also! check [this question and answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171426/google-maps-api-v3-infobox-js-removed/)!!, there are users who experienced issues with the same library, to get more information. Read all answers, as replacing https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn with https://rawgit.com/googlemaps/... is not a correct solution, you should download the library assets (in your case the image) into your project and reference them from there or use CDN (but not git!).