# Unable to add markers to Marker Cluster

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to add my markers to a MarkerCluster, I have the following code, I push each `Marker` to the `markers` array. I then declare `markerCluster` and add in the `markers` array and the map. However my MarkersClusterer never display, could anyone suggest why this is?

```
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

//do ajax request, add marker on success
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

    for (key in response) {
        if(response[key]["post_code"] === undefined ){
            return; 
        }
        (function () {
            var markers = [];
            var address = response[key]["address"];
            $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+response[key]["post_code"]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
                var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
                var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    content: address
                });
                markers.push(Marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'click', function () {    
                    infowindow.setContent(this.content);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            });
        })();
    };
});
```

Comment: In `markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);` is `markers` defined? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Hi, it's defined just below  (function () {

Comment: It's not in the same scope so it's undefined... but that's not the only error. Can you create a fiddle so I can play with it? I've done this many times, the fix is pretty easy but I need to play with your fiddle.

Comment: I have var markers = []; to a global scope (outside of 'document.ready'), however it is still undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `markers` variable is defined outside of the scope when it's used in `MarkerClusterer`. You add markers to different `markers` which only exists inside the anonymous `(function(){..` . To understand this problem, I suggest you to take a look at [this](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions) or [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) article.

**EDIT**

ALSO! As user vyx.ca pointed out, `MarkerClusterer` has `addMarker()` method which is the [advised way](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/examples.html) of adding markers to the clusterer.  My code now reflects the change.

There are commented parts of code referring to the changes:

```
var markers = []; //HERE!!
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

    for (key in response) {
        if(response[key]["post_code"] === undefined ){
            return; 
        }
        (function () {
            //REMOVE THIS !! var markers = []; 
            var address = response[key]["address"];
            $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+response[key]["post_code"]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
                var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
                var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    content: address
                });
                //Changed to line below - markers.push(Marker);
                markerCluster.addMarker(Marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'click', function () {    
                    infowindow.setContent(this.content);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            });
        })();
    };
});
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, change `markers.push(Marker);` to `markerClusterer.addMarker(Marker);`

Comment: Thanks! this works now, I have a strange issue where no icon appears as the cluster (I get only a number). I'll look in to this though.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37184213/2661226
You might just have to set the correct url of the image.