# Where is the Google Marker Cluster?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

After adjusting to the new movements from Google to Git, one issue still persists.

> http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/images/m1.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

What shall I do get the marker cluster rendered on the map, instead of a `?` ?

I am using a coffee script:

```
class RichMarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker #inherit from builtin builder
  #override create_marker method
  create_marker: ->
    options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
    @serviceObject = new RichMarker options #assign marker to @serviceObject

  rich_marker_options: ->
    marker = document.createElement("div")
    marker.setAttribute 'class', 'marker_container'
    marker.innerHTML = @args.title
    _.extend(@marker_options(), { content: marker })

  infobox: (boxText)->
    content: boxText
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
    boxStyle:
      width: "300px"

  # override method
  create_infowindow: ->
    return null unless _.isString @args.infowindow
    boxText = document.createElement("div")
    boxText.setAttribute("class", 'marker_info_box') #to customize
    boxText.innerHTML = @args.infowindow
    @infowindow = new InfoBox(@infobox(boxText))

@buildMap = (markers)->
    handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { Marker: RichMarkerBuilder} } #dependency injection

    #then standard use
    handler.buildMap { provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
      markers = handler.addMarkers(markers)
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers)
      handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

Comment: https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087583/google-maps-not-working-in-https#answer-37093736

Comment: I edited the question to provide the coffee script I am using. Don;t know how to  put this ` 
cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/…` with the coffee script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download this image and include it in your project: https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png
2. Search (CTRL+SHIFT+F on most of IDEs, depends on what IDE/platform you are using) your whole project, including libraries for this string "http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/images/m1.png"
3. Replace the found occurrence(s) with link to the downloaded image.

(Please don't reference the image directly from https://cdn.rawgit.com... as the URL can change in the future again, as it did couple of weeks ago and you will have the same problem. Just download it between your project's image files and reference it from there)

Comment: I downloaded the "png". The problem is that considering the coffee script posted I don't know how to write the line(s) of code required there to include this "png" file as the image to be used.

Comment: The code you have posted concerns RichMarker library not MarkerClusterer library. Try to find a code where you create MarkerClusterer and post that.

Comment: This is the problem, I wasn't able to find one (that code to be used / posted).

Comment: What IDE are you using? Why don't you just search whole project for "MarkerClusterer" or "http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/images/m1.png" ? There has to be an occurrence somewhere.

Comment: I am using Ruby on Rails and the editor is Atom. I executed the command "Cmd+Shift+F" to search for the occurrence of the text "m1.png" in all files of the project. No occurrence of that text was found.

Comment: And what about "MarkerClusterer" ? Or "markerclusterer" or "marker-clusterer"? Maybe some other library includes it.

Comment: I did a global search for the text "MarkerClusterer" and another one for the text "marker-clusterer". These are not present in any file, no mater the type or extension across the project.

Comment: This is strange it has to be included somewhere. Maybe if you searched in the source files in the browser (if they are not obfuscated) that could give you more clue. But like this I cannot help you furthermore.