# GMLib Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101 (v1.5.3)

Tags: javascript, delphi, internet-explorer, delphi-xe7, gmlib

I have an application using the latest version (v1.5.3) of GMLIB.  Starting today, the map now generates the above generic error when I place an object on the map.  My application has not changed.  I also tested the GMLIB MegaDemo that was provided and the same error is generated when starting the map - previously there was no error.  I am using XE7 and have IE11 installed.

It appears the same error occurred several years ago and Catedill released an update to fix.

Below is the function and parameter I pass when the error occurs:

'MakeMarker'
'2,false,false,true,false,false,true,35.7519302368164,-121.285972595215,true,''001: SAMPLE'',true,'''',0,'''',false,0,0,0,true,''mtStyledMarker'',''siBubble'',''#0000FF'',''#FFFFFF'',''#00FF00'',false,false,true'

Anyone else just start getting this error?

Comment: It appears the map.html file includes two resources no longer available:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js

and

http://gmlibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Resources/MaxZoom.js

I have StyledMarker.js so I can host that file, but I don't have MaxZoom.js

Comment: Hi, it's true, this resource is no longer available. Mark, if you have StyledMarker.js, please, send me and I will upload to github (to GMLib 1.x folder). Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks!!

Comment: You can find it at:  https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/1ae531383555f40ef69d78574bf8a128b4c19517/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have made a solution. I have found StyledMarker.js and I have uploaded it into the GitHub GMLib repository.

Now, you only need to do this changes:

- Into .\resources\map.html file replace this url:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js

by this other:

https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js

or

https://cdn.rawgit.com/cadetill/gmlib_v1/master/Resources/StyledMarker.js

- Recreate resource file executing  .\resources\rc.cmd
- Build (no compile) all GMLib

Another option is download changes from [GitHub repository](https://github.com/cadetill/gmlib_v1).

More info about the problem [here](http://www.cadetill.com/en/problema-con-gmlib-v1-x/).

Regards and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using your own development copy of the Google utility script, I'd recommend changing the url in your .\resources\map.html from:

```
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js
```

to the following cdn prefixed version of the source library:

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js
```

In production, you really should be using the cdn version of the script as it has [no traffic limits or throttling and the files are served via a super fast global CDN](https://rawgit.com/).  However please bear in mind that, as a free service, it offers [no uptime or support guarantees](https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#i-need-guaranteed-100-uptime-should-i-use-cdnrawgitcom).

Accessing files hosted from Git is covered in more detail in the following SO answer:

[Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/1301937)

If you'd still prefer to use your own copy, for the same reasons I'd suggest using your cdn copy:

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/cadetill/gmlib_v1/master/Resources/StyledMarker.js
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have changed my post