# Google Maps MarkerManager V3 (404) not found

Tags: markermanager

We used the Markermanager from this location for years https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/src/markermanager.js. Today it vanished silently and we found [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/) that it was moved to github.

You will find a new packed version here:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markermanager/src/markermanager_packed.js. I hope this thread helps others to find it faster then I was.

Please also see Chris Cook's answer, he provides the CDN url...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Google moved the source over to GitHub](http://google-opensource.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html) a while back, the new [GitHub version](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markermanager) can be accessed from [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) by using the following script urls (standard and packed versions):

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markermanager/src/markermanager.js
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markermanager/src/markermanager_packed.js
```

Whilst the above urls (with the cdn prefixes) have [no traffic limits or throttling and the files are served via a super fast global CDN](https://rawgit.com/), please bear in mind that [RawGit is a free hosting service and offers no uptime or support guarantees](https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#i-need-guaranteed-100-uptime-should-i-use-cdnrawgitcom).

Accessing files maintained via GitHub is covered in more detail in the following SO answer:

[Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/1301937)

**This post also covers that, if you're linking to files on GitHub, in production you should consider targeting a specific release tag to ensure you're getting a specific release version of the script.**

**For example, you could target the 1.2 release of the markermanager library with the following script urls (standard and packed versions):**

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/markermanager/1.2/markermanager.js
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/markermanager/1.2/markermanager_packed.js
```

**Alternatively, you could download and include the library directly in your project for production purposes.**

Answer (score 2):

Full list of v3-utility-library on GitHub:

[v3-utility-library](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library)

Tnx for link to markermanager.js

I also use markerwithlabel.js in my project, and get error 404.

New link to markerwithlabel.js

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js
```