# Where can I find Google Maps v3 markermanager.js

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markermanager

It appears that markermanager.js is no longer available on googlecode.com which has been closed. I have looked for an equivalent on Github, but so far without success. I can find marker-clusterer etc. but my code is built to run with markermanager.js.

Can anyone tell me where it has gone, please?

Answer (score 8):

Following [Google's move of the source](http://google-opensource.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html), the new [GitHub version](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/packages/markermanager) can be accessed via [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) (a content deliver network with [no bandwidth limits that's focused on performance, reliability, and security](https://www.jsdelivr.com/about)) by using the following script urls (standard and packed versions):

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/googlemaps/v3-utility-library@markermanager/1.2/markermanager.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/googlemaps/v3-utility-library@markermanager/1.2/markermanager_packed.js
```

These urls specifically target the 1.2 release of the markermanager library - as covered in the following SO answer, **in production you should consider targeting a specific release tag to ensure you're getting a specific release version of the script**:

[Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/1301937)

**Alternatively, you could download and include the library directly in your project for production purposes.**

Comment: It looks as if I didn't drill down far enough in my previous searches. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped and please can you accept the answer and mark is as useful (if you haven't already)

Comment: RawGit no longer active. This post needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this @Brainware - I've updated the answer to replace RawGit with jsdelivr.net

Comment: If you use a CDN, make sure you get on their Newsletter. The last one I used shut down on me and I wasn't aware they were going to do that. Be safe.