# why class function method not call in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to make simple example of event module of node.I saw this video.I am trying to make same example on code pen.But it is not working why ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvjNglsyOHs&index=9&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b

here is my code

http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/dMBVaz?editors=1010

```
var {EventEmitter}=events;
class Todostore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.todo= [{
                hse: 'asd'
            }, {
                hse: 'adas'
            }]
  }
  getAll(){
    return this.todo;
  }
}
const todostore =new Todostore;
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      console.log('----')
         this.state = {
             data:todostore.getAll()
         };
    }

    render() {
        return <ul > {
                this.state.data.map((item) => {
                    return <li 
                     > {
                        item.hse
                    } < /li>;
                })
            } <
            /ul>
    }

}

React.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

One, for future reference, if you are linking to some raw Javascript on GitHub in your file, this:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gozala/events/master/events.js`

Will cause an error:

> Refused to execute script from ... because its MIME type (text/plain) is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

You can use rawgit.com instead as a workaround to this

`https://rawgit.com/Gozala/events/master/events.js`

More info on this topic can be found here: [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122)

---

The second and much *larger* issue, is that Codepen (along with other JS playground type sites like JSFiddle and JSBin) are built for client side code. And you are linking to a module which is designed to be used in a server-side CommonJS environment, like Node.js. It's not going to work.

If you have Node installed on your system you should be able to test it out locally in a basic setup by grabbing the module with npm/bower:

```
npm install --save eventemitter3
```

And importing it in your test file:

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'eventemitter3';
// Rather than: var {EventEmitter}=events;
```

Comment: so there is no way to make eventemitter examplee online

Comment: Not in any 'plug in some code and it works' kind of way. A simple local environment is a good thing to have by your side anyway, it's pretty common to have to test both server-side & client-side code at once, and you can re-use it as a general sandbox for other code you may want to try out in the future.