# How to load another jQuery script from url using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery function to load a jQuery script stored in either Pastebin (http://pastebin.com/raw/AAirNTgx) or GitHub (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DarkPotatoKing/darkpotatoking.github.io/master/IskoDuler.js) ?

Comment: Can't you just add a `<script>` tag? Either statically or by using jQuery?

Comment: why do you need to load a js file from code?

Comment: `$.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DarkPotatoKing/darkpotatoking.github.io/master/IskoDuler.js", function(data){$('head').append('<script>' + data + '<\/script>')});`

Comment: Our "app" is a Javascript bookmarklet that when run on certain site will do something, however when we have to update the script we have to tell the users to delete their current bookmark and get the new version of the bookmark from the site. So instead, I thought what if I just store the script somewhere then just load that from jQuery, so that when I update it I'll just edit the script online but the users will still use the same bookmarklet since it's just calling the script online

Comment: @DarkPotatoKing You aware this is against their TOS?!

Comment: @A.Wolff GitHub or Pastebin?

Comment: @DarkPotatoKing Both i guess...

Comment: @A.Wolff Nope, I'm not aware. Do I have other options if I want to continue what I'm planning?

Comment: @DarkPotatoKing I'm not that familiar with bookmarklet but i'm sure if instead of asking question regarding workaround, you ask question regarding your former issue, you'll get more relevant answer. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) So i think you should delete this question and ask a new one. But maybe i'm wrong and the way you are trying to handle it is a relevant way, i just don't know

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success //success callback handler..
});
```

or `$.getScript()`

and use url like `https://rawgit.hubusercontent.com` NOT `raw.githubusercontent.cpm`. why? [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)

I was able to load . [Check jsbin here](https://jsbin.com/hececipoco/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: $.getScript("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DarkPotatoKing/darkpotatoking.github.io/master/IskoDuler.js") returns "undefined"

$.ajax({
  url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DarkPotatoKing/darkpotatoking.github.io/master/IskoDuler.js",
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
}); returns "ReferenceError: success is not defined "

Comment: success is a function call to do on receiving your script.. you can remove that parameter if you are not interested in it.

Comment: I removed success and now it just returns "undefined"

Comment: can you paste the code what you are trying in question?
you can check in network tab of browser whether the file has been loaded or not..

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DarkPotatoKing/darkpotatoking.github.io/master/IskoDuler.js",
  dataType: "script"
});

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by replacing your source or path file,

```
<script>
   $( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/load.html #projects li" );
</script>
```