# Isotope horizontal layout not working in Chrome and Firefox; possible bug in tumblr

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, horizontal-scrolling, tumblr-themes

While working on a tumblr theme, I noticed that even though Isotope's horizontal 'horiz' layout works perfectly in Safari, in Chrome and Firefox, the layout just doesn't seem to work. When I type something in the search box (filtering), the layout reloads properly, but doesn't seem to obey css height/width restrictions on the container. The page whose effects work in Safari but not in Chrome/Firefox : [01](http://victoirelle.tumblr.com).

Desandro's horizontal layout example on codepen was working on all browsers, so to check if it may be tumblr messing up, I reduced the problem to **exactly** what DeSandro had written in his codepen example. Even then, **it did not work on tumblr, in both Chrome and Firefox**. It's working in Safari. The page of the reduced problem : [02](http://phoenale.tumblr.com).

It's important to note that the default layout, 'masonry', works on all browsers. I have not found anyone using Isotope's horizontal 'horiz' layout on a tumblr theme, so I cannot compare my theme with theirs or learn from them. Is this a possible bug on tumblr's part? If anyone can pinpoint the problem and explain what is going on here so that I can make the theme look like how it does in Safari, I would be so thankful!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. Chrome and Firefox were not loading the horizontal.js script correctly, " because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable". Linking the file to `rawgit.com/...` worked (referring to an answer for [a previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)).