# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined; When script included another error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at index.html:76`. I looked at some previous solutions which suggested including `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` in `<head>` . But when I do so, **another** error pops up:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

index.html:78 Uncaught ReferenceError: VideoFrame is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:78)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
```

Here is a complete version of my source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<!--    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />-->
    <title>Video Test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js'></script>
    <style>
      #container {
        position: relative;
      }
      #overlay {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;

      }
      #base {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
      }
      #radio1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 383px;
        left: 462.5px;
      }
      #radio2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 401px;
        left: 466px;
      }
      #radio3 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 422.5px;
        left: 468px;
      }
      #radio4 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 443px;
        left: 467px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="frame">  
      <span id="currentFrame">0</span>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
      <button id="play-pause">Play</button>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="overlay">
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="1" id="radio1"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="2" id="radio2"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="3" id="radio3"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="4" id="radio4"/>
          <input type="button" id="continue" value="Continue"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="base">
        <video width="960px" height="540px" id="video">
          <source src="videos/event_0_Junli_Standing_20150322_181647_00_0.6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var currentFrame = $('#currentFrame');
        var video = VideoFrame({
            id : 'video',
            frameRate: 5,
            callback : function(frame) {
            currentFrame.html(frame);
            }
        });

        $('#play-pause').click(function(){
            if(video.video.paused){
                video.video.play();
                video.listen('frame');
                $(this).html('Pause');
            }else{
                video.video.pause();
                video.stopListen();
                $(this).html('Play');
            }
        });
      });


      //////
      var arr = []
      document.getElementById("continue").addEventListener("click", function() {
          var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')          
          if (radios.length > 0) {
            arr.push(radios[0].value)
          }
          console.log(arr)
      }) 

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add VideoFrame cdn also

Comment: @Durga how do I do so?

Comment: add a jQuery.js first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` error is obviously because the jQuery library isn't loaded, when you add jQuery, the error goes away because jQuery is now loaded and working. You get the `VideoFrame` error because there's nothing called `VideoFrame` defined, it seems like you're missing a dependency.

The reason you never got the `VideoFrame` error when jQuery was missing is because the `$` error meant the script never even got as far as the `VideoFrame` part before it crashed.

**Update**:
The missing dependency appears to be this one: https://rawgit.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js

Comment: Ahh I understand. I'm using the code from http://jsfiddle.net/Ck6Zq/184/. It does seem to work in Fiddle. How would I include VideoFrame? Is that part of a Javascript Library?

Comment: @AlexKer If you look at the external libraries in the fiddle, you'll see it includes this library: https://rawgit.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js

Comment: Yep I included that as well as JQuery Library first. I'm getting Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. Please see updated code above

Comment: @AlexKer Try to add `type="text/javascript"` as an attribute on the script tag

Comment: which script tag, I have two in head and one in body. Edit: I tried all three script tags, doesn't solve the error.

Comment: @AlexKer Preferably all of them! But most importantly the one that loads the VideoFrame library

Comment: Yeah I tried that. The error stems from line 1, is it because of my type of HTML?

Comment: @AlexKer When an error occurs on "line 1", that's usually just misleading. I think this may be an issue with HTTPS. You see, the library is loaded over HTTPS but you probably host your page on HTTP. I suggest you either find an HTTP CDN hosting this library, or just download the script and place it together with your other files

Comment: Solved it. See my post. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got the call to the jQuery CDN commented out so it's not actually being loaded, hence the reference error. Uncomment it and you should be set.

Comment: But the point is that when I uncomment it, I get the second error.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of skimmed and missed that part. Like Mikael Lennholm said, `VideoFrame` is not defined. I'd put money on Our_Benefactor's suggestion of including the script.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CDN to your scripts

```
<script src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js'>
```

Comment: I get another error for including this. Please see updated code and error above.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!

Here is the solution for the `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` error:

Changing

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js'>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://rawgit.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame/master/VideoFrame.min.js'></script>
```

See here for detailed explanation: [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)