# How do I load files from GitHub rather than locally? [React App from GitHub Pages]

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I have finally *incorrectly* published my React App onto GitHub Pages. I believe that the issue is that my React App is trying to pull files from my local computer instead of my GitHub (which I don't want anyways). How would I change this?

My website has the error:

*Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/numak/Desktop/MyWebsite/dist/bundle.js*

This first issue (of probably many) is in my *index.html* file which sources my *bundle.js* file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <title>React Starter</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="root"></div>
            <noscript>
                You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
            </noscript>
            <!-- Here is the problem apparently -->
            <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
  </html>
```

I'm not sure if this is actually an issue with the way I sourced it. It could also have to do with how I setup my website in my package.json or webpack.config.js files.

Here is a link to my GitHub branch that hosts the files for the GitHub Pages website:

https://github.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite/tree/websiteVersion1

Here is a link to my GitHub Pages branch:

https://github.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite/tree/gh-pages

Here is a link to my GitHub Pages website:

https://numakarolinski.github.io/PersonalWebsite/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where will your `bundle.js` file be located on the server? Will it be in a `dist` folder? It might just work if you write `src="/dist/bundle.js"` instead.

Comment: You could try `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite/websiteVersion1/dist/bundle.js` instead of `../dist/bundle.js` but i'm not sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by *MaddEye* helped me discover my final solution.

The comment was slightly wrong because `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite/websiteVersion1/dist/bundle.js` has a MIME type of *text/plain*, but a MIME type of *text/javascript* is required.

I found that you can replace *raw.githubusercontent* by *cdn.rawgit* with a final solution of: `https://cdn.rawgit.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite/websiteVersion1/dist/bundle.js`

I found this solution here: [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)