# How do I link to a javascript code I'm working on with git?

Tags: git

I'm using jsdelivr to point to a javascript file I'm working on in Git. I have done a fair amount of research, mostly by following these instructions:

[Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)

I cannot figure out a way to have a master link to my file that updates as I commit edits. I can't use a commit hash, because that changes every time. I just want the URL to my javascript file to always reflect the latest commit and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git.  You want to deploy your source code somewhere which Git is, frankly, unconcerned with.

Comment: Actually, it does. I use jsdelivr to host the link directly. I want to be able to edit the code, commit, then have that code functioning on my other site live. I figured git was the best way to do this.

Comment: The question you link to suggests GitHub does not want you to do this. It's probably a significant additional load on their servers that they don't really want to see.

Comment: Ugh......

jsDelivr handles this perfectly fine. That's what it's for. Please read the post more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I'm looking for: codepen.io.

Codepen lets you work on a JS file in-browser and in a sandbox, then use a direct link to that file that another site can use. This is perfect for me, because the site I need to embed the JS in isn't serving millions of visitors.

Answer (score 1):

jsDelivr will provide a CDN mirror of a Github repository. If you want to see your commits on jsDelivr it's necessary to get your commits onto Github. Because Git is decentralized `git commit` only commits to your local repository. You then need to `git push` your changes to Github. Then jsDelivr can sync with Github.

See [Working With Remotes in the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) and [Managing Remotes on Github](https://help.github.com/categories/managing-remotes/) for more information.

Comment: How do I do this in a browser?

Comment: @PatrickHennessey You do it wherever you're editing the files and making the commits. You normally don't do that in the browser, unless you're editing files directly on Github.