# Get a variable from Github

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, webflow

I have a json file that's an ABI for a smart contract.  I am building a site in Webflow, but due to the 10000 character custom code limit, I need to host the json for the smart contract elsewhere.

I have it on Github at: https://github.com/learyjk/baddognft/blob/main/ABI.js

What I would like to do is have a variable in the custom code section of Webflow and just be able to call ABI so that I can instantiate a web3 contract.  I was able to get it working using gitcdn.link but it's not working anymore for some reason.

Another option I played around with but wasn't able to get working were $.get("link here").  I also tried jsdelivr

but I keep getting "ABI not defined" error.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not JSON when you precede it with `var ABI =`. It's then a javascript array.

Comment: What's the jsdelivr link you're using? Does `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/learyjk/baddognft/ABI.js"></script>`  work? (it does for me). Saying you tried something isn't that helpful if you don't show the relevant code from the attempt.

Comment: You probably at the very least want to put a CDN in front of this, if not host it elsewhere.  GitHub's raw endpoints aren't supposed to be a CDN, and there are rate limits. If your repository exceeds them, you'll be asked to bring them down pretty quickly.  Putting them in smart contract will generate a lot of requests.

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen that worked for me (I kept the variable declaration in there).  Sorry I forgot to include the code.  I think mine wasn't working because I had included a /blob or /dist before the file name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the raw version of the file from github, try changing the link to this:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learyjk/baddognft/main/ABI.js
```

Looking at the file though, you have `var ABI = [// your stuff]`. Which is invalid json. You have the extension correct so maybe that was just a typo in your question...

Comment: I don't think rawgit will work if this is part of a script inclusion. See [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)