# Quarto with a CSS in the parent directory

Tags: css, yaml, quarto

I want my CSS file to be shared by several Quarto R presentations, so this CSS file should be placed in a top directory. But Quarto seems to allow CSS files only in the same directory, or in a child directory. I have tried all these configurations without success, starting with the `css` option in the YAML header:

```
---
title: "my title"
author: "my name"
format:
  revealjs: 
    css: ...
---
```

- ../styles.css
- "../styles.css"
- ..\styles.css
- "..\styles.css"
- *symlink* 'style.css'
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zoometh/thomashuet/master/teachings/stats/styles.css
- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zoometh/thomashuet/master/teachings/stats/styles.css"
- https://github.com/zoometh/thomashuet/blob/main/teachings/stats/styles.css
- C:/styles.css
- "C:/styles.css"

But also outside the YAML, in the narrative parts and code chunks

`<link href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Rprojects/thomashuet/teachings/stats/styles.css">`

`<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxx/xxx/master/teachings/stats/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

```
``{css}
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zoometh/thomashuet/master/teachings/stats/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
``
```

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Rprojects/thomashuet/teachings/stats/styles.css">`

So relative paths, absolute paths (local or GitHub), symbolic links, calls outside the YAML header, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share a common CSS stylesheet among several RevealJs presentations, using a CSS stylesheet stored in a GitHub repo seems a good idea.

But using `raw.githubusercontent` to link the stylesheet will not work, because  `raw.githubusercontent` makes all files use the `text/plain` MIME type, even if the file is a CSS or JavaScript file. Therefore, the following will not work.

```
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zoometh/thomashuet/master/teachings/stats/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

One possible solution to this problem is to use [`jsDelivr.net`](https://www.jsdelivr.com/?docs=gh) (A free CDN for open-source projects). We can follow the steps described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/10858321),

**Steps:**

- Find your link on GitHub, and click to the "Raw" version.
  Copy the URL. In your case which is, `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zoometh/thomashuet/main/teachings/stats/styles.css`.
- Change `raw.githubusercontent.com` to `cdn.jsdelivr.net`.
- Insert `/gh/` before your username.
- Remove the branch name (`main` in this case).

So the final URL would look like, `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/zoometh/thomashuet/teachings/stats/styles.css`. Now you can use this URL within a `link` tag in a html file and then include the html file using the `include-in-header` yaml key in the qmd file.

**style.html**

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/zoometh/thomashuet/teachings/stats/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**presentation.qmd**

```
---
title: "my title"
author: "my name"
format:
  revealjs: 
    include-in-header: style.html
---
```

---

Another good solution to this problem is to use [`Github pages`](https://pages.github.com/) which will host your repo at a special URL like `https://‹your_github_userName›.github.io/‹repo›`. And you can use this URL to point to a specific folder/files in your repo.